# How to point all notices and warnings to exceptions?

Tags: php, exception

Is it possible to point all notices and warnings inside `try/catch` in exceptions. But do it only in try, the rest of the code should use default error handling. The main problem is that the try is in the while loop and can be called several times so i think it isnt a good idea to use `set_error_handler` and `restore_error_handler` several times. Maybe php have something like in java?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use error handler. But you can configure the error handler to throw or not to throw exceptions:

```
class ErrorHandler {
  public static $throw = false;

  public static function handler() {
    if(self::$throw) throw new Exception();
  }
}

set_error_handler(array('ErrorHandler', 'handler'));
ErrorHandler::$throw = true;
```